# NPM/React: copyfiles not running correctly

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-run

Django 2.0, 
Node.js 8.11.4

I have a djanog project of the format:

```
reactify/
└── src/
    ├── reactify-ui/
    |   ├── build/
    |   |   └── static/
    |   |       └── js/
    |   |           └── main.3425.js
    |   └── package.json
    └── staticfiles/
        └── js/
            └── reactify-django-us.js
```

I want to replace the content of `\reactify\src\staticfiles\js` with what is in `\reactify\src\reactify-ui\build\static\js\*`

My `packages.json` looks like this

```
    "scripts": {
     ...
    "copy-build-js": "copyfiles -f 'build/static/js/*.js' '../staticfiles/js/'",,
     ...
  }
```

When I run `npm copy-build-js` I get the following output:

```
> reactify-ui@0.1.0 copy-build-js    C:\Users\Owner\dev\reactifydjango\src\reactify-ui
> copyfiles -f 'build/static/js/*.js' '../staticfiles/js/'
```

It looks like it works, but when I inspect the file in the target location `../staticfiles/js/`, it hasn't changed. 
I validate it by

```
changing the file before I run the command,
do an `ls -lrth` to get the timetamp, 
wait a minute so the timestamp changes, 
run the command `npm copy-build-js`,  
and then doing an `ls -lrth` on the target location and seeing that the timestamp isn't post hasn't changed.
I also look at the file and it is the same.
```

Why would the copyfiles not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the structure correct, but the `copyfiles` package has some quirks that you missed. Use this as your script:

`"copy-build-js": "del /F \"../staticfiles/js\" && copyfiles -E -f \"./build/static/js/*.js\" ../staticfiles/js"`

The double quotes here are required, so you need black slashes before each to escape them.

The `copyfiles` package does not have an option to replace all files in a directory even if the filenames don't exist, so first you have to run `del /F \"../staticfiles/js\"` to delete all files in the `src/staticfiles/js` directory. This command assumes you're on Windows.

Then you run `copyfiles -E -f \"./build/static/js/*.js\" ../staticfiles/js`. What you missed was that when using wildcards/globs with this package (`*`), you have to **double** quote the location. If a location doesn't have a wildcard in it, you don't need quotes at all. I added in the `-E` flag that will throw an error if files aren't copied, which could potentially save you trouble later on.

Comment: I am on windows. This is great! Is there anyway to force it to delete the files in the directory without asking for permission?